# A word that means 'excessive encouragement'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means excessive encouragement.

Example: 
"We encourage our kids to study - but when does encouragement become excessive encouragement"?

punishment? overzealousness?

Comment: OCD = obsessive compulsive disorder. Obsessive compulsion.

Comment: If it's excessive, it's not encouragement. See the dictionary.

Comment: @Kris, exactly. At what point does active encouragement discourage. You can lead the horse to water and give it opportunity and encouragement to drink and so on. But ducking it's head underwater would be excessive, cruel and counterproductive etc. I think counterproductive might be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, not being sure exactly what you have in mind,

> We encourage our kids to study - but when does encouragement become *harassment*?

or, more non-specifically

> We encourage our kids to study - but when does encouragement become *counter-productive*?

Comment: I think counterproductive is what I'm looking for. At the point the kids rebel even if they are interested - the encouragement is overcooked!

Answer (score 1):

what about **"enforce"** and **"force"** ?

> We force our kids to study

Also the word **"oblige"** can deliver a similar meaning. 
Another example I've seen a lot is **"pressure"**

> We pressure our kids to study

Comment: I like pressure.

Comment: Me too, I use it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that  [overtask](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overtask) may fit the context described:

> (tr) to impose too heavy a task upon

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need for a specific word. Just drop the final "encouragement". If a stronger statement is desired, substitute "overwhelming" for excessive.

Comment: Good point, but that's not an answer, it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks **[badger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/badger)** their kids to study.

> to ask or tell someone again and again to do something

Answer (score 0):

***exhort***

> [1.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exhort) Strongly encourage or urge (someone) to do something
>
> [2.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhort) To urge by strong, often stirring argument, admonition, advice, or appeal

---

There isn't a significant dictionary entry but ***overencourage*** is a word also.